# Using Python3, is there a simple way to filter a dataframe [WaypointID1, WaypointID2] to get only starting waypointIDs to final waypointIDs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, routes, dataset

I am looking for a method to summarize a 2 columns dataset like this :

```
Source, Target
PlaceID1,CrossroadID3
PlaceID2,CrossroadID3
CrossroadID3,PlaceID4
PlaceID4,PlaceID5
PlaceID4,PlaceID6
PlaceID6,PlaceID7
```

To

```
Source, Target
PlaceID1,PlaceID4
PlaceID2,PlaceID4
PlaceID4,PlaceID5
PlaceID4,PlaceID6
PlaceID6,PlaceID7
```

```
CrossroadID3 is used to identify link between PlaceID1 to PlaceID4
CrossroadID3 is used to identify link between PlaceID2 to PlaceID4
CrossroadID3 is not a place, so we dont want to keep it
```

My dataset contains only the description of [Source|Target] links, representing a set of routes starting at a PlaceID, passing through some of these PlaceIDs and ending at other PlaceIDs. I would like to reduce this dataset to just the start and end PlaceIDs, eliminating CrossroadIDs.

I wonder if there is a simple method, with Python3 and maybe Pandas or a more specialized library.
Note that my dataset contains only IDs, no coordinates :)

Thank you for help,
New in Python and new in stackoverflow ^^

Comment: I think you can easily represent it with `networkxx` package as a graph and then reduce it as you wish